# how do I extract data between two characters in java

Tags: java, split

```
String text = "/'Team1 = 6', while /'Team2 = 4', and /'Team3 = 2'";

String[] body = text.split("/|,");
String b1 = body[1];
String b2 = body[2];
String b3 = body[3];
```

Desired results:

```
b1 = 'Team1 = 6'
b2 = 'Team2 = 4'
b3 = 'Team3 = 2'
```

Comment: You might need to use a parser here, rather than `split()`.  It's just complex enough that simple tools like `split()` don't work well.  Can you provide us with some constraints and invariants?  Will the data you are interested in always contain a `=` between the team name and the number?

Comment: It looks like you want to extract strings delimited at the start by a slash (`'/'`) and at the end by a comma (`','`). Is that right? If so, you can probably do this with a regex and matcher. Do you also need the single quotes in the result strings? Will the quoted text itself ever contain a slash or comma? If so, parsing with a regex might be a little more challenging, but probably still doable.

Comment: Note that he also wants to ignore words like "while" and "and" after the comma.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex. Something like this:

```
String text = "/'Team1 = 6', while /'Team2 = 4', and /'Team3 = 2'";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\w+\\s=\\s\\d+)").matcher(text); 
// \w+ matches the team name (eg: Team1). \s=\s matches " = " and \d+ matches the score.
while (m.find()){
    System.out.print(m.group(1)+"\n");
}
```

This prints:

Team1 = 6

Team2 = 4

Team3 = 2

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways you can do this, but in your case I'd use [regex](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/).

I don't know Java but think something like this regex pattern should work:

`Pattern compile("\/'(.*?)'")`

A random regex tester site with this pattern is here: https://regex101.com/r/MCRfMm/1

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say "friends don't let friends use regex" and recommend parsing this out.  The built-in class `StreamTokenizer` will handle the job.

```
   private static void testTok( String in ) throws Exception {
      System.out.println( "Input: " + in );
      StreamTokenizer tok = new StreamTokenizer( new StringReader( in ) );
      tok.resetSyntax();
      tok.wordChars( 'a', 'z' );
      tok.wordChars( 'A', 'Z' );
      tok.wordChars( '0', '9' );
      tok.whitespaceChars( 0, ' ' );
      String prevToken = null;
      for( int type; (type = tok.nextToken()) != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF; ) {
//         System.out.println( tokString( type ) + ":  nval=" + tok.nval + ", sval=" + tok.sval );
         if( type == '=' ) {
            tok.nextToken();
            System.out.println( prevToken + "=" + tok.sval );
         }
         prevToken = tok.sval;
      }
   }
```

Output:

```
Input: /'Team1 = 6', while /'Team2 = 4', and /'Team3 = 2'
Team1=6
Team2=4
Team3=2
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

One advantage of this technique is that the individual tokens like "Team1", "=" and "6" are all parsed separately, whereas the regex presented so far is already complex to read and would have to be made even more complex to isolate each of those tokens separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can split on "a slash, optionally preceded by a comma followed by zero or more non-slash characters":

```
String[] body = text.split("(?:,[^/]*)?/");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String text = "/'Team1 = 6', while /'Team2 = 4', and /'Team3 = 2'";
        char []textArr = text.toCharArray();
        char st = '/';
        char ed = ',';


        boolean lookForEnd = false;
        int st_idx =0;
        for(int i =0; i < textArr.length; i++){
            if(textArr[i] == st){
                st_idx = i+1;
                lookForEnd = true;
            }
            else if(lookForEnd && textArr[i] == ed){
                System.out.println(text.substring(st_idx,i));
                lookForEnd = false;
            }
        }

        // we still didn't find ',' therefore print everything from lastFoundIdx of '/'
        if(lookForEnd){
           System.out.println(text.substring(st_idx)); 
        }

    }  
}

/*

'Team1 = 6'
'Team2 = 4'
'Team3 = 2'

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use split and a regex using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) matching either the start of the string followed by a forward slash or matching a comma, match not a comma one or more times and then a forward slash followed by a positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that what follows the alternation is a `'`

`(?:^/|,[^,]+/)(?=')`

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Start non capturing group

  - `^/` Assert the start of the string followed by forward slash
  - `|` Or
  - `,[^,]+/` Match a comma followed by match not a comma one or more times using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and then match a forward slash
  - `(?=')` Positive lookahead to assert what follows is `'`
- `)` Close non capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dYo0dF/1) - [Java demo](http://rextester.com/IWOLD37280)

**Getting a match instead of split**

If you want to to match a pattern like `'Team1 = 6'`, you could use:

`'[^=]+=[^']+'`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PjoW6n/1) - [Java demo](http://rextester.com/IWU1016)